# PDF of product of r.v.'s + constant

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, bayesian

Assume we have the marginal pdf's $f_{X}(x)$ and $f_{Y}(y)$, but not necessarily their analytical expressions; they do not exist in my case even if I can compute their values numerically. $Y$ is always positive.

**EDIT: I analyzed my problem better and I think we can assume that X and Y are independent (the numerical approximation of the pdfs do not share any parameters).**

Now, we have a new random variable $Z := XY + d$, where $d$ is just a constant.
How can I calculate values of $f_Z(z)$ using $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$?

I started with the reasoning that
$$f_Z(z) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{Z,Y}(z,y)dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{Z|Y}(z,y)f_Y(y)dy$$

The function $g_1(x) := f_X(x-d)$ is a pdf, but the function $g_2(x) = f_X\left(\frac{x-d}{y}\right)$ is not, and in order to obtain a proxy for $f_{Z|Y}(z,y)$ I seem to need to normalize by calculating the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{X}\left(\frac{x-d}{y}\right)dy$. (Is there any easier way to calculate the normalization constant?)

And then I am using
$$f_{Z|Y}(z,y) = \frac{f_{X}\left(\frac{z-d}{y}\right)}{\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{X}\left(\frac{z'-d}{y}\right)dz'}$$

Finally, I was hoping this would imply that

$$f_Z(z) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left[\frac{f_{X}\left(\frac{z-d}{y}\right)}{\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{X}\left(\frac{z'-d}{y}\right)dz'} f_Y(y)\right]dy$$

And that the joint density would be written as

$$f_{Z,Y}(z,y) = \frac{f_{X}\left(\frac{z-d}{y}\right)}{\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{X}\left(\frac{z'-d}{y}\right)dz'} f_Y(y)$$

This came up because I have numerical approximations for $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$. This expression means I would have to calculate a lot of integrals for the normalization constants because of $Y$, but I managed to make that work with a discrete grid approximation, so it's fine for calculating a single value $f_Z(z^*)$. The real problem is that when I do a cubature to calculate the integral of the joint density, it doesn't add up to one, so I don't trust my results. This cubature is computationally prohibitive in this application (fitting a a given model, calculating the likelihood point by point); so I am wondering if there's anything wrong in my reasoning and that's why I am not getting a pdf at the end.

Should I do it using this formula here?
[Distribution of the product of two random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_of_the_product_of_two_random_variables)
$$f_{Z}(z)=\int _{\mathbb{R}}f_{X}\left(\frac{z}{y}\right){\frac {f_{Y}(y)}{|y|}}\,dy$$
If so, why would my approach not work as opposed to this one (I have yet to try this one out)?

Comment: You straight up don't have enough information from $f_X$ and $f_Y$ to get $f_Z$, it depends on the dependence structure.

Comment: I added an edit to clarify that part. I believe we can assume independence here between $X$ and $Y$. My question remains because I don't understand why the joint pdf I obtain doesn't have volume one.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then it is much easier to avoid conditioning and instead just directly write out the CDF of the product and then differentiate.

Comment: So my normalization step in $f_{Z|Y}(z,y)$ is what's wrong here?

Comment: Your first step is right, but now to get $f_{Z \mid Y}$ you look at $F_{Z \mid Y}(z \mid y)$ and differentiate wrt $z$, which more or less leads you back to the path that Wikipedia wrote out.

Comment: All right, let me try this and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I just confirmed it works, even numerically. Do you want to write it as an answer to get the points, @Ian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General rule of thumb: if you don't know exactly what you are doing, don't do any manipulation directly with densities. Always pass via CDFs and/or probabilities of events.

Here, you want $f_Z$, so you want to get $F_Z$ and then differentiate that. From the total probability formula we can connect that to the conditional CDF:

$$F_Z(z)=\int F_{Z \mid Y}(z \mid y) f_Y(y) dy.$$

Next we connect the conditional CDF back to the CDF of $X$. Note that because you have to divide by $Y$ to get an inequality with $X$ isolated, the formula depends on the sign of $y$:

$$F_{Z \mid Y}(z \mid y)=P(XY+d \leq z \mid Y=y) \\
=\begin{cases}
P(X \leq (z-d)/y \mid Y=y)=F_X((z-d)/y) & y>0 \\
P(X \geq (z-d)/y \mid Y=y)=1-F_X((z-d)/y) & y<0 \end{cases}.$$

Note that the last equations in the chain used independence. Now you can substitute into our first equation to get

$$F_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^0 F_X((z-d)/y) f_Y(y) dy + \int_0^\infty (1-F_X((z-d)/y)) f_Y(y) dy.$$

Now you can differentiate with respect to $z$ on both sides to recover $f_Z$.